# I want to get total stock in Laravel and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am creating a Pharmacy Management System Using Vuejs. PHP, Laravel, jQuery. Now in this part I want to get the stock when pharmacist/medicine seller search medicine for sell.

Example: when a pharmacist just enter key of medicine name, I want to display related medicine name, company name, generic name, tp(Buying Price), MRP (Selling Price), available stock

My medicines table structure:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('pharmacy');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('stored_by');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('updated_by')->nullable();

$table->string('is_branch_medicine')->default('No');

$table->string('branch_id')->nullable();

$table->string('invoice_no');

$table->string('item_status');

$table->string('medicine_name');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('generic_name_id');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('company_name_id'); //Company name/id should be unique for each invoiceNo

$table->bigInteger('medicine_qty');

$table->float('medicine_tp');

$table->float('medicine_mrp');

$table->float('tax')->default(0);

$table->float('discount')->default(0);

$table->string('expire_date');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('total');

$table->string('invoice_created_date');

$table->string('item_store_date');

 $table->timestamps();
```

I have already write a query for getting data for sale but I can`t minus/calculate total sold medicine from total stock. My query:

```
$data = Medicine::where([

["pharmacy", "=", $authUserPharmacy],

["is_branch_medicine", "=", "Yes"],

["branch_id", "=", $branch_id],

["medicine_name", "LIKE", "%$medicineKey%"],

["expire_date", "!=", $today]
 ])

->select(
'pharmacy', 'branch_id', 'medicine_name', 'generic_name_id', 
'company_name_id', 'medicine_tp', 'medicine_mrp',
DB::raw('sum(medicine_qty) as stock')
           )

->groupBy('pharmacy', 'branch_id', 'medicine_name', 'generic_name_id', 'company_name_id', 'medicine_tp', 'medicine_mrp')

->with(['get_generic', 'get_company'])

->get();
```

I am getting data fine but I want to show my total stock by Subtraction total sell from stock (`DB::raw('sum(medicine_qty) as stock')` of medicines table)

my sell_table

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('pharmacy');

$table->string('is_branch_medicine')->default('No');

$table->string('branch_id')->nullable();

$table->string('medicine_name');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('generic_name_id');

$table->unsignedBigInteger('company_name_id');

$table->float('medicine_tp');

$table->float('medicine_mrp');

$table->bigInteger('medicine_qty_for_sell');

$table->bigInteger('selling_date');
```

Actually I want to show how many medicine available for sell according to pharmacy, medicine_name, generic_name, company_name? I mean stock of medicine. How can I solve this complex query?

Comment: Can you please format your source code? Use three ` for this

Comment: Can U please post the raw SQL Query?

Comment: Did you mean pure mysql query? #Jaymin    I have built this using laravel.... I just want to know how to get stock after selling any medicine please......